# Highcharts - show only years in xAxis

Tags: highcharts

I have grouped data by year and want to show only 2 bars (2014 + 2015).

Any ideas why highchart also includes months between the bars?

```
"chart": {
      "type": "column"
    },
    "plotOptions": {
      "column": {
        "stacking": "normal"
      },
    },
  "series": [
    {
      "data": [
        [1388534400000,88]
      ],
      "name": "First",
      "id": "series-8"
    },
    {
      "data": [
        [1388534400000,39]
      ],
      "name": "2nd",
      "id": "series-9"
    },
    {
      "data": [
        [1420070400000,34]
      ],
      "name": "3rd",
      "id": "series-10"
    }
  ],
  "xAxis": {
    "type": "datetime",
    "dateTimeLabelFormats": {
      "year": "%Y"
    }
  }
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/747hs83s/

I would like to have only 2014 and 2015 labels on x-axis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a pointRange as 1 year (365 * 24 * 3600 * 1000, time in miliseconds) and set tickInterval with the same value.

```
"plotOptions": {
  "column": {
  pointRange: 365 * 24 * 3600 * 1000,
    "stacking": "normal"
  },
},
"xAxis": {
    tickInterval: 365 * 24 * 3600 * 1000,
  "type": "datetime",
  "dateTimeLabelFormats": {
    "year": "%Y"
  }
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/3d3jzywq/

Answer (score 2):

The answer to "why does the chart show months" is simply that there are months between your data points to be shown, and the chart has no way of knowing that you don't want it to show them.

There are probably numerous solutions, but the one I would use is the `pointRange` property - tell the chart that each column represents a year, and it will display it accordingly:

```
pointRange:86400000 * 365//one year
```

Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/747hs83s/2/

By default, it will show the years as labels. If you show/hide series, that may change. There are a number of ways to format the label as well.

**Label formatting references:**

- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.labels.format
- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.labels.formatter
- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Highcharts.dateFormat
- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Highcharts.dateFormats
- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.dateTimeLabelFormats